# Calling laravel controller inside a route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've Laravel route with GET & POST as below

```
Route::get("test1","Api\TestController@test1");
Route::post("test1","Api\TestController@test1");
```

Now I'm trying to check some condition & if it remain true then I want to call controller else i want to show error without even going into controller.

Like:

```
Route::get("test1",function(){

$aaa=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(preg_match("/sender_id=TEST/is", $aaa)){

@Call_controller: "Api\TestController@test1" 

}else{
echo "some error found"; die();}

});
```

How to call controller inside function of route.

I don't want to check this in controller because its a API & when i'm getting 10000+ hits per second, calling a function inside laravel load multiple dependences resulting wastage of server resources.

- Same has to be done with GET & POST

Comment: Why not just use [rate limiting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/rate-limiting#introduction)?

Comment: Its a API based website on which we're getting thousand of hits per second we can't limit that as we charge for each hit.

Comment: I don’t get your point about `load multiple dependences resulting wastage`. If that is your concern, don’t use Laravel or any framework for that matter. If the request reaches the `Route::` part, everything is booted already, so one controller won’t crash your server.

Comment: Are you trying to differentiate between good hits and bad hits? What are you trying to approve vs disapprove?

Comment: We checking same condition inside controller & all our CPU, RAM got used up & when we put this condition in route itself, no server resource wastage. 

Is this possible to call controller inside a function of routes?
If no then can we redirect that user to different route like test1_new without showing him the new url else he'll hit new url directly !

Comment: This is what [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware) is for. You define the Route, apply the Middleware (as a "before" middleware, so it runs before the Controller code), and check whatever you need to in the middleware. If it's "bad" (whatever that means), trigger an error and never run the Controller code. If it's "good", run the Controller code.

Comment: Your example code is misleading, you need to provide more detail. If your route is `test` you will never have `sender_id=TEST` in your request uri.

Answer (score 1):

While you can call the controller using `(new Api\TestController())->test1()`, the right way to do is:

- Create a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#defining-middleware) (say "`MyMiddleware`") and add your logic in the handle() method:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $aaa=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (preg_match("/sender_id=TEST/is", $aaa)) {
      return $next($request);
    }
    abort(403);
}
```

- Now use the middleware in the route:

```php
Route::get("test1","Api\TestController@test1")->middleware(MyMiddleware::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both your route functions are the same, you can use middleware.

Create `check` middleware `php artisan make:middleware check`

```
class check
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(preg_match("/sender_id=TEST/is", $request->getUri())) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else{
            return "some error found";
        }
    }
}
```

And in route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'check'], function () {
    Route::get("test1","Api\TestController@test1");
    Route::post("test1","Api\TestController@test1");
});
```